# ¿Cómo es posible hacer un menú responsive mediante CSS?

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los diseñadores me han pedido que haga el diseño móvil como abajo, estoy tocando posiciones absolutas pero no consigo dar con los problemas.Tiene que quedar como la imágen de abajo. Supongo que mediante CSS podría posicionarlo pero me está costando bastante.

Aquí código:

```
    <div class="d-block top-bar wrapper bg-greycustom py-1 topHeaderWrapper">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12 px-0 px-lg-2 ">
                <div class="ml-2 d-none d-lg-block">
                </div>

                <div class="d-flex align-items-center pt-lg-1 pb-lg-1">
                  <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-2 d-flex color-white align-items-center">
                        <div class="iconos-envio d-flex">

                          <div class="iconos-envio d-flex flex-column">
                            <span class="icon-envio lato-bold fs-lg-07">icon</span>
                            <span class="lato-bold fs-lg-07">Envio gratuito</span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="iconos-envio d-flex flex-column">
                            <span class="icon-billete lato-bold fs-lg-07">icon</span>
                            <span class="lato-bold fs-lg-07">Envio gratuito</span>
                          </div>


                        </div>
                      </div>
                     
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                          <a class="icon icon-user text-white mr-45" href="<?php echo home_url('/mi-cuenta/') ?>">
                          </a>
                          <div id="icon-cart" class="icon-cart-wrapper rel-wrapper">
                            <a class="icon icon-cart" rel="nofollow" href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>">
                              <?php $items_cart = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); ?>
                              <?php if ($items_cart) : ?>
                                <span><?php echo $items_cart; ?></span>
                              <?php endif; ?>
                            </a>
                            <div class="minicart-modal">
                              <?php woocommerce_mini_cart() ?>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

No sé como lo veis.

Comment: Deberias añadir el codigo completo para poder ver como podemos ayudarte respetando la estructura que tu tienes hecha ya.

Comment: Muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento: lee [ask].

Comment: Y en vistas de desktop, cómo tienes pensado visualizarlo?